# Вывод единицы в строке

Tags: php, строки, modx, echo

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Есть следующий код, который формирует определенную строку в html в зависимости от того, работаем ли мы с авторизованным пользователем или нет.

```
 <?php
/**webTracking snipper**/
$userId = $modx->getLoginUserId();
if ($userId) {
    $gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-66286163-1', { 'userId': '".$userId."' });";
    //$gacode = "ga('create', 'UA-66286163-1', 'auto');";
    echo $gacode;
} else {
    echo "ga('create', 'UA-66286163-1');";
}
?>
```

И все работает, вот только почему-то после echo появляется единичка. Скрин прилагаю. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

html-код чистый проверяла. Если убрать php код, то строка пропадает вместе с единицей. Может кто знает природу этого непонятного глюка и как убрать эту единичку :) Если это важно, то CMS MODX

Comment: Покажите код после того что вы выставили.

Comment: Как вы вызываете этот код? Если через снипет, то снипет не должен использовать операторы `print` или `echo`, он должен вернуть переменную `$output` которая и будет выведена. Иначе может быть непредсказуемый результат.

Comment: Tunker спасибо. В этом и была проблема, что я использовала echo в сниппете. Буду теперь знать такие тонкости :)